# MarkLogic - How to Escape Question Mark in a request uri regular expression?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, escaping, marklogic

My main goal is that I have this expression in a uri-rewriter:

```
<request uri="^/(.+)/name=(.+)$" endpoint="/endpoint.xqy">
   <uri-param name="level">$1</uri-param>
   <uri-param name="name">$2</uri-param>
</request>
```

which reads uris of the form .../level/name= __

but I want to replace the slash before the name with a question mark to read the following form  .../level?name= __

I want to treat the question mark as literal in the uri. I saw that special characters in a regex can be escaped with a " \ "

But it does not work on question marks or ampersand ... It works on + or . Which is weird. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score -2):

The `?` character can be surely escaped using `\` in RegEx but I am not sure about the MarkLogic. Maybe because it is defining uri endpoints, it is not taking uri parameters into consideration.